# How to deploy from Cloud9 to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-cloud9

I have my app developed in Cloud9, and I would like to use the terminal with GIT commands to deploy my app to a EC2 instance. The objective is to make the app run in the EC2 instance.

Is it necessary to deploy the app to a EC2 instance, or is it already in a EC2 instance and I just have to open the URL of the app?

My cloud9 environment is in a region and my EC2 Instance is in another region (I'm telling this just in case it changes something in the process).

I already did it to Heroku, but I can't see how does it work to a EC2 instance.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy your app to an EC2 instance from the Cloud9 console, you have a couple of options.  Please note, you only need to use **one** of these options, not all of them.  I would generally recommend option #1 for your case based on your original question.

1. Use [AWS amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/) instead of EC2 (Amplify is Amazon's version of Heroku)
2. Use the [AWS CDK client](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/), and specifically, you'll want to look at [`Instance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Instance.html) and either utilize `userData` or [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) to build your app and deploy to EC2.
3. Use the [AWS client](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to deploy Cloudformation templates (this is the lower-level version of option #2 and will require more boilerplate)
4. Connect your Git repository to AWS CodePipeline and run a CI/CD flow to deploy it to EC2 on every commit to the `main`/`master` branch (this is fairly complicated)

The most important thing to understand is that Cloud9 is simply an IDE (integrated development environment) that is *deployed to* an EC2 instance that is managed by AWS (not you).  Cloud9 is not a tool for actually deploying code (you'll need to use one of the options I mentioned above for that).